# Creating a zend project on Zend Studio 9.0.1

Tags: zend-framework, createprocess

I've just installed the latest Zend Studio along with the latest zend server on my PC (windows 7 - 64 bit).

Now I'm trying to create a zend framework project by creating a **NEW -> Local PHP Project** , choosing a zend framework in location :

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs

which is by default my localhost folder.And finally when the project created all I get is 3 included libraries :

> Javascript Resources , PHP Include Path , PHP Language Library.

And No additional folders created.
But What with the basic structure of the zend project ? 
How can I create the default "Template" zend project ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mystery was solved !

All I had to do is allow "WRITE" permission to my

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\htdocs

folder.

That's it , so simple !

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE:** *Glad you managed to resolve the issue, All the best. Dave*

I just tried going through the process and it worked fine for me creating the extra folders.

Just check you selected the right option when going through the wizard as Zend Framework needs to be selected (see image below).

[image: Make sure Zend Framework is selected]

You could try using Zend Tool instead if that doesn't work.

The documentation is [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.tool.framework.clitool.html) if you haven't used it before - also loads of tutorials online you can watch too.

When you create a new controller using it, you can have it automatically create an index action and index view created.

Likewise if you create a new action in a controller using it the view can be created automatically saving you some time.

If that doesn't work for you either, you may want to try reinstalling Zend Studio.

Hope this helps.

All the best,

Dave